# Let $f: A\to B$, $g: B\to C$ and $h: B\to C$ be functions. Suppose that for all $x\in A$ we have $g(f(x)) = h(f(x))$. Prove or disprove $g=h$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Because a single input for a function cannot have different outputs, I have written $g(f(x))= h(f(x))$ as $g(y) = h(y)$ for all $y\in B$. Is this enough to say that $g=h$? The question doesn't specify anything regarding the injectivity of the functions, so I am a little stumped on where to go next. Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Injectivity isn't the problem - surjectivity is. $g(f(x)) = h(f(x))$ shows that $g$ and $h$ are equal over the image of $f$, but if $f$ isn't surjective then consider what happens with $y \in B$ if $y$ isn't in the image of $f$.

Comment: We can draw this conclusion for any such $C, g, h$ iff $f$ is surjective. That is, surjections are exactly the epimorphisms in the category of sets.

Answer (score 3):

It suffices to consider that $f$ is not surjective to provide a counter-example.

Indeed, let us consider that $A = B = C = \{0,1,2\}$.

Now we can define $f$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
f = \{(0,0),(1,1),(2,0)\}
\end{align*}

Consequently, if one assumes that $g$ and $h$ are given by:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
g = \{(0,0),(1,1),(2,1)\}\\\\
h = \{(0,0),(1,1),(2,2)\}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

we arrive at the following relations
\begin{align*}
g\circ f = \{(0,0),(1,1),(2,0)\} = h\circ f
\end{align*}

but we know by construction that $g\neq h$ since $g(2)\neq h(2)$.

So we can conclude the proposed claim is false.

Hopefully this helps !

Answer (score 2):

Let $A,B,C = \mathbb{R}$, let $f$ be the constant function $f(x) = 2$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Take $g(x) = x$, $h(x) = 4 - x$.

Then $g(f(x)) = 2 = h(f(x))$ for all $x$, but $g \not= h$.